# 3D Bin Packing using memory based learning

Tags: optimization, machine-learning, knn, bin-packing

I need to solve a 3D Bin Packing Problem using previous solutions already stored. I thought of using memory-based learning like the K-Nearest-Neighbors method. Are there any other ways to do it?